# WinRar and 7zip command to extract archive in new folder

Tags: windows, command-line, compression, 7-zip, winrar

Good morning
I would like to know if there is a command in WinRar and 7zip that allows me to extract a compressed file into a new folder with the same file name, equivalent to right-clicking and selecting the <<extract in 'filename'/>> option.
At the moment I only have the command in which you need to specify the folder in which the file will be extracted

In WinRar:

```
WinRar x ArchiveFile *.* destDir
```

In 7zip:

```
7z x ArchiveFile -o destDir
```

Please help me achieve this in WinRar and 7zip. Thank you

Comment: For 7-Zip, the easiest way might be to use a batch file, repeating the %1 argument. Something like  `7z.exe e %1 -oC:\temp\%1 -r` should extract all files in the input *file* to the output *folder* of the same name in the C:\temp\ folder. Untested. See https://7-zip.opensource.jp/chm/cmdline/commands/extract.htm

Comment: Thanks for your response. I would like to do it from a command line since I use autohotkey and from there I extract the name of a file using another function. →→→  Thus =   C:\Program Files\7z.exe e %1 "C:\Users\User\Downloads\Untitled (19).zip" -o C:\temp\%1 -r  ←←←. It doesn't work for me, I guess because these commands are only for .batch files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WinRar:

```
WinRAR x ArchiveFile -ad
```

the -ad switch will extract to a folder with the same name as your archive file

7zip:

```
7z x ArchiveFile -o*
```

the -o* switch will extract to a folder with the same name as your archive file